How prevent CircularProgressIndicator child from expanding the parent in Jetpack Compose?
I am trying to add ProgressIndicator onto a Button. I would like the progress indicator to take up the whole height of the button with 5.dp vertical padding, where the height of the button is determined by the content.
So I added the isLoading: Boolean parameter and I update the contentPadding based on that. I decided to leave the content in the composition and just set .alpha(0f) on it to keep the size of the button same. But I can't get the progress indicator to be the right size. If I put .matchParentHeight() modifier on it, it inherits the height of the content itself (does not fill the whole height of the button up to the padding) or it just overflows ouside of the button. Alternatively if I remove this modifier, the indicator increases the height of the button when tapped.
How to do it?
@Composable
fun Button(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    isLoading: Boolean = false,
    shape: Shape = ButtonDefaults.shape,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(),
    elevation: ButtonElevation? = ButtonDefaults.buttonElevation(),
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource? = null,
    content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    val layoutDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current
    androidx.compose.material3.Button(
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = modifier
        ,enabled = enabled,
        shape = shape,
        colors = colors,
        elevation = elevation,
        border = border,
        contentPadding = if(!isLoading) {
            contentPadding
        } else {
            PaddingValues(
                start = contentPadding.calculateStartPadding(layoutDirection),
                end = contentPadding.calculateEndPadding(layoutDirection),
                top = 5.dp,
                bottom = 5.dp
            )
        },
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
    ) {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        ) {
            val contentAlpha = if (isLoading) { 0f } else { 1f }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .alpha(contentAlpha)
            ) {
                content()
            }

            if (isLoading) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color = if (enabled) {
                        colors.contentColor
                    } else {
                        colors.disabledContentColor
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .matchParentSize()
                        .background(Color.Yellow)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

Edit: I am using this to preview it:
@Preview
@Composable
fun ButtonPreview() {
    Column {
        Button(
            onClick = {},
            isLoading = false,
        ) {
            Text("Test")
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {},
            isLoading = true,
        ) {
            Text("Test")
        }
        androidx.compose.material3.Button(
            onClick = {},
        ) {
            Text("Test")
        }
    }
}

Edit 2:
My goal is to have the loading button behave in a same way the default button does. But the text does not always use the full available height on the button, so I would like the progress indicator to use all the available height while keeping the button same size.

Answer from @tyg has a small issue where the progress indicator can appear outside of the visible button. I managed to improve it with onSizeChanged modifier. But this is not recomended by the docs:

There are no guarantees onSizeChanged will not be re-invoked with the
same size.
Using the onSizeChanged size value in a MutableState to update layout
causes the new size value to be read and the layout to be recomposed
in the succeeding frame, resulting in a one frame lag.
You can use onSizeChanged to affect drawing operations. Use Layout or
SubcomposeLayout to enable the size of one component to affect the
size of another.

But I could not figure it out using Layout or SubcomposeLayout.
Edit: It still had an issue when explicitly setting .height(...) modifier on the button. I did manage to fix it using Layout, but I could not avoid using the onSizeChanged modifier anyway. Here is the new code.
@Composable
fun Button(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    isLoading: Boolean,
    shape: Shape = ButtonDefaults.shape,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(),
    elevation: ButtonElevation? = ButtonDefaults.buttonElevation(),
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource? = null,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    val verticalIndicatorPadding = 5.dp

    val layoutDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current

    var contentHeight by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    Layout(
        modifier = modifier
            .minimumInteractiveComponentSize(),
        measurePolicy = { measurables, constraints ->
            val measuredContentButtonPlaceable = measurables[2].measure(constraints)

            val paddingTop = contentPadding.calculateTopPadding().roundToPx()
            val paddingBottom = contentPadding.calculateBottomPadding().roundToPx()
            val paddingVertical = paddingTop + paddingBottom
            val layoutWidth = measuredContentButtonPlaceable.width
            val layoutHeight = if (constraints.hasFixedHeight) {
                measuredContentButtonPlaceable.height
            } else {
                // Button has invisible "minimumInteractiveComponentSize" area around it,
                // therefore the real visual height has to be calculated like this
                val realContentButtonHeight = contentHeight + paddingVertical
                max(realContentButtonHeight, ButtonDefaults.MinHeight.roundToPx())
            }
            val indicatorButtonConstraints = Constraints.fixed(layoutWidth, layoutHeight)
            val contentButtonPlaceable = measurables[0].measure(indicatorButtonConstraints)
            val indicatorButtonPlaceable = measurables[1].measure(indicatorButtonConstraints)
            layout(layoutWidth, layoutHeight) {
                if (isLoading) {
                    indicatorButtonPlaceable.place(0, 0)
                } else {
                    contentButtonPlaceable.place(0, 0)
                }
            }
        },
        content = {
            // 0: contentButton
            // Button with content inside
            androidx.compose.material3.Button(
                onClick = onClick,
                modifier = Modifier,
                enabled = enabled,
                shape = shape,
                colors = colors,
                elevation = elevation,
                border = border,
                contentPadding = contentPadding,
                interactionSource = interactionSource
            ) {
                content()
            }

            // 1: indicatorButton
            // Button with progress indicator inside
            androidx.compose.material3.Button(
                onClick = {},
                modifier = Modifier,
                enabled = enabled,
                shape = shape,
                colors = colors,
                elevation = elevation,
                border = border,
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(
                    start = contentPadding.calculateStartPadding(layoutDirection),
                    end = contentPadding.calculateEndPadding(layoutDirection),
                    top = verticalIndicatorPadding,
                    bottom = verticalIndicatorPadding,
                ),
                interactionSource = interactionSource
            ) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color = if (enabled) {
                        colors.contentColor
                    } else {
                        colors.disabledContentColor
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .size(0.dp)
                        .aspectRatio(1f, true)
                )
            }

            // 2: measuredContentButton
            // It is used to measure the preferred size of contentButton, but is not placed
            // Also the onSizeChanged modifier is used to measure the real content height
            androidx.compose.material3.Button(
                onClick = {},
                modifier = Modifier,
                enabled = enabled,
                shape = shape,
                colors = colors,
                elevation = elevation,
                border = border,
                contentPadding = contentPadding,
                interactionSource = interactionSource
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .onSizeChanged {
                            contentHeight = it.height
                        }
                ) {
                    content()
                }
            }
        }
    )
}


The issue is that the CircularProgressIndicator has a fixed size of 40.dp1. You can explicitly set the size to something else, but it won't automatically resize according to the available space.
Keeping your approach of letting the Button's content define the overall height, one way to adjust the CircularProgressIndicator's size accordingly is to reduce its size and then let it grow to the available space:
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min),
) {
    Button(/*...*/)

    if (isLoading) {
        CircularProgressIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(5.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .size(0.dp)
                .aspectRatio(1f, true),
        )
    }
}

Note that I moved the CircularProgressIndicator out of the Button and placed both in a Box. That is necessary because of the different padding you require: If you change the padding you also change the size, which you want to stay the same.
With height(IntrinsicSize.Min) you let the Button's height determine the overall height of the Box because the CircularProgressIndicator's size is explictly set to zero.
Then the CircularProgressIndicator's height is inflated again with fillMaxHeight() to match the container's height which is now the height of the Button. The width of the CircularProgressIndicator is then set to the same as the height with aspectRatio(1f, true) so it finally is a circle again.
Everything put together it would look like this:
@Composable
fun Button(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    isLoading: Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    shape: Shape = ButtonDefaults.shape,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(),
    elevation: ButtonElevation? = ButtonDefaults.buttonElevation(),
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    progressIndicatorPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(vertical = 5.dp),
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource? = null,
    content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        androidx.compose.material3.Button(
            onClick = onClick,
            modifier = modifier,
            enabled = enabled,
            shape = shape,
            colors = colors,
            elevation = elevation,
            border = border,
            contentPadding = contentPadding,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = if (isLoading)
                    Modifier
                        .alpha(0f)
                        .semantics { invisibleToUser() }
                else
                    Modifier,
                content = content,
            )
        }

        if (isLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(
                color = if (enabled) {
                    colors.contentColor
                } else {
                    colors.disabledContentColor
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(progressIndicatorPadding)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .size(0.dp)
                    .aspectRatio(1f, true),
            )
        }
    }
}

Note that I removed the default value of this new Button's isLoading parameter to better disambiguate it from the standard Button. I also made the progress indicator's padding of 5.dp a parameter (progressIndicatorPadding), you might want to adjust that later on.
And finally, when the Button's content is made invisible, the semantics should reflect that as well so that accessibility services like TalkBack are not confused by the invisible but still present content of the button. From Compose 1.8.0 onwards (still in alpha at the time of writing) use hideFromAccessibility() instead of invisibleToUser() for that.

1The CircularProgressIndicator's overall size is defined as ProgressIndicatorTokens.Size - ProgressIndicatorTokens.TrackThickness * 2 which is 40.dp with the current Material 3 library (version 1.3.1).

Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Great thinking with moving the progress indicator outside of the button. There is one small issue for me, that the outer box is for some reason larger than the button (by about 5dp). I could cheat it by doing padding 10dp instead of 5, but I would rather to fix it properly.

I cannot see a difference between this Button and a regular Button. Can you provide an example?

Hmm, I can get a picture of it, but idk how to share it to you. I'll edit the question with the code I'm using to preview it.

Clickable surfaces have a minimum size of 48.dp for accessibility reasons. The Button may look smaller, but it actually is at least 48.dp in height. A Box around a smaller Button will therefore include additional space between the visible part of the Button and the border of the Box. Since the approach from my answer uses the Button's overall size (i.e. at least 48.dp) to determine the CircularProgressIndicator's size, for small Buttons the visual padding seems to be smaller than it actually is. You would need an entirely different approach to fix that.

I was hoping for the solution to behave the same way the default button behaves (which I didn't really state well in the question, so I'll edit that in). I guess I can solve it by setting the minimal height of the button to 48.dp. I'll leave the question open for now in case someone comes up with something better, otherwise I'll accept your answer, cause it's really well done and exhaustive.

The size issue originates from the default Button. The Button from my answer therefore behaves the same as the default Button. The only thing that's different is that it also displays a CircularProgressIndicator (without touching the Button's size). The minimal clickable surface area of 48.dp is a feature that share all Material 3 components and has nothing to do with the code from my answer.

Yeah, but the visual result is simply not there. If the button has 1 line of text, then it visually appears smaller then than 48.dp and therefore the progress indicator just does not have vertical padding of 5.dp (or whatever) to the displayed button. Yes it does have the correct padding to the button component, which is larger than the visible button because of that minimal clickable area. But what I care about is the visible button, not the invisible clickable area when it comes to padding of visible components.

I am sorry, but while your answer definitely did help me, it ultimately did not do what I wanted sufficiently enough. I did manage to do it myself in the end, by using completely different approach with Layout.
